# dynamically adding two matrices ; error in line 27 and 41

Tags: c, for-loop, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int** addMatrix(int**, int, int, int**);

int main(void)
{
    int i, j, m, n, **p, **q, **sum; //i = row, j = column

    printf("Enter the size of the row: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    printf("Enter the size of the col: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    p = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        p[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    } 

    printf("Enter the elements of the Matrix M:\n"); //taking input
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
           scanf("%d", ((p+i)+j)); // LINE 27
    }

    q = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        q[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    } 

printf("Enter the elements of the Matrix N:\n");
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
       scanf("%d", ((q+i)+j)); // LINE 41
}

sum = addMatrix(p, m, n, q);

printf("Vector Sum:\n");
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        printf("%d ", *(*(sum+i)+j));
    printf("\n");
}
}

int** addMatrix(int **p, int m, int n, int **q)
{
int i, j, **add;
add = (int**)malloc(m * sizeof(int*));

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    add[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
} 

for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        *(*(add+i)+j) = *(*(p+i)+j) + *(*(q+i)+j);
}    
return add;
}
```

main.c:27:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
main.c:41:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ [-Wformat=]
the lines for taking the input of the matrix. this is the error I am getting.

Comment: What is the type of ```p```? What type does the ```%d``` format specifier expect?

Comment: `p=malloc(` **m** `* sizeof(...))` and subsequent `for(int i = 0; i <` **n** `; ++i)` don't go well together if `m` and `n` are not equal...

Comment: try replacing `((p+i)+j)` with `(p[i]+j)` or `(*(p+i)+j)` on line 27 and same approach for line 41

Comment: You should really choose better variable names, e.g. `rows` and `columns` or shorter `cols` make much clearer what they actually stand for.

Comment: And `p[i]` is more readable than `*(p + i)`. It gets worse when you're dealing with pointers to pointers. If you want to learn about pointers, implement trees and linked lists.

Comment: Off-topic, but your wording might be misleading: The *size* of a row is the number of columns and vice versa. Assuming classic layout of outer dimension of the array of arrays being rows and inner one columns then you invert rows and columns...

Comment: Consider using VLA types. Just do: `int (*p)[n] = calloc(m, sizeof *p);`

Comment: @tstanisl Oh, my bad, *of course* I do mean... Rewriting the comments ;)

Comment: Array of pointers to individual arrays is a pretty inefficient matrix representation, by the way, as it requires double indirection to access matrix fields as well as multiple allocations and deallocations. Better in this respect is a single 1D array of size `rows * columns`, though you lose the convenient double index syntax (`matrix[row][column]`) and would instead have calculate the index explicitly (`index = row * columnCount + column`). Some other parts, in contrast, get simpler then, e.g. filling all fields:

Comment: `int* matrix = malloc(sizeof(*matrix) * rows * columns); if(!matrix) { /* TODO: error handling!!! */ } int* m = matrix; for(size_t i = 0; i < rows; ++i) { for(size_t j = 0; j < columns; ++j) { scanf(m); ++m; } }`

Comment: Extending on my code example: Have you noticed the error handling? You should *always* check the result of `malloc` for possibly being a null pointer and add appropriate error handling, otherwise you run into undefined behaviour if allocation actually fails (admitted happens rarely...).

Comment: @Aconcagua, `scanf(m)` is not going to work very well

Comment: @tstanisl Of course not... I've been lazy, as QA already proved knowing how to do correctly, so should be just short for `scanf("%d", m)`. Now getting punished for, having to write much more in another comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

The for loops like this

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

are wrong. You have to use the variable m (the number of rows) instead of n (the number of columns)

```
for(i=0; i<m; i++)
{
    p[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
}
```

The calls of scanf like this

```
scanf("%d", ((p+i)+j));
```

are also wrong.

You have to write

```
scanf("%d", *(p+i)+j );
```

The expression `*(p+i)+j` is equivalent to `p[i] + j` that can be also written like `&p[i][j]`.

And you should free all the allocated memory before exiting the program.

In general you should check whether values for the variables `m` and `n`  are valid and whether memory was allocated successfully. And it will be better if the variables `m` and `n` will have an unsigned integer type as for example `size_t` instead of the signed integer type `int`.